# Cordova + Facebook throws error on run

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, cordova, ant

I'm trying to set up a basic cordova + facebook app and have done the following

```
C:\>cordova create hangout com.bkardi.hangout hangout
Creating a new cordova project with name "hangout" and id "com.bkardi.hangout" at location "C:\hangout"

C:\hangout>cordova platforms add android
Creating android project...
Project successfully created.


C:\hangout>cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via plugin registry
Installing "org.apache.cordova.device" for android

C:\hangout>cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via plugin registry
Installing "org.apache.cordova.console" for android
```

And then to install the facebook plugin doing the following

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="MY_APP_ID" --variable APP_NAME="MY_APP_NAME"
```

I then attempt to run the shell by doing the following:

cordova run android but get the following error

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\adt\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing
 this line:
C:\adt\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error outpu
t for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

C:\hangout\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\hangout\platforms
\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: C:\hangout\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit co
de 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\kardi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```